# Valores duplicados em coluna que é chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Ao tentar inserir um novo dado em determinada tabela (funcionario), tenho uma coluna chamada "gerenteID" que é FK da própria tabela "funcionario".

Durante o cadastro eu envio o ID de um outro funcionário nessa coluna, só que esta retornando que já tenho o valor cadastrado na coluna. E tenho na verdade, mas não é para ocorrer isso. Pois tenho uma coluna que executa a mesma função chamada "empresaID" que é FK também, mas de outra tabela, mas não ocorre o problema de valores duplicados.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '10' for key 'gerenteID'
```

Comment: O índice não esta bloqueando valores duplicados?

Comment: Você não colocou a coluna `gerenteID` como `UNIQUE`?

Comment: consegui resolver pessoal.

Dei um SHOW INDEX FROM 'tabela'

e depois um ALTER TABLE 'tabela' DROP INDEX 'chave'

Agora esta indo padrão